# FB private messages from email

Tags: facebook

Given that I know user's email address (full name, address and some more info) and I know that this user used his email to register on FB. Is it possible to send private message to the user in question using his email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Using email address you can send email to the user.

Comment: Actually you are not right. It took me few minutes to find a way and it is pretty straight forward. When you try to search for people on FB using email address, it will give the person who owns the email. All you need then is PHP curl class to wrap interaction with FB and using your FB profile, to send the private message. However, I am wondering if there is more straightforward way.

Comment: "PHP curl class to wrap interaction with FB and using your FB profile" --- it is illegal. When you find **legal** way - put the downvote back. Until that moment - return the reputation of this answer to 0, please.

Comment: @zerkms: It is not illegal as long as the person who's FB account is going to be used to send those messages is friend of the recipient. FB does not limit program activity on behalf of the user until it does not breach their TOS or is done without user knowing how the wrapper works.

Comment: @Guy: it violates TOS "You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or collects Facebook usernames or passwords." (c) https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: @zerkms, and I am not doing doing either of those, i.e., I am not requesting/collecting Facebook users usernames or passwords.